# Laravel + VueJs + Webpack + Karma = world of pain

Tags: laravel, vue.js, karma-jasmine

Is it possible to write unit tests for VueJs if you are using Laravel's Elixir for your webpack configuration?

VueJs 2x has a very simple example for a component test: [Vue Guide Unit testing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html)

```
<template>
  <span>{{ message }}</span>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        message: 'hello!'
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.message = 'bye!'
    }
  }
</script>
```

and then...

```
// Import Vue and the component being tested
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from 'path/to/MyComponent.vue'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('has a created hook', () => {
    expect(typeof MyComponent.created).toBe('function')
  })
  it ...etc
})
```

and gives an example of a karma conf file here: [https://github.com/vuejs-templates](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/test/unit/karma.conf.js)

But the Karma configuration file requires a webpack configuration file

```
webpack: webpackConfig,
```

The only problem is the Laravel's Elixir is creating the webpack configuration so it can't be included.

I have tried creating another webpack configuration file based on the example from https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack.

Something like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                        // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                        // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
                        'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                        'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                    }
                    // other vue-loader options go here
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}
```

and included it like...

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Mar 15 2017 09:47:48 GMT-0500 (CDT)
var webpackConf = require('./karma.webpack.config.js');
delete webpackConf.entry;

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    webpack: webpackConf, // Pass your webpack.config.js file's content

    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },
```

But I am getting errors that seem to indicate that webpack isn't doing anything.

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/components/test.vue
Module parse failed: /var/www/test/resources/assets/js/components/test.vue Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|     <span >{{test}}</span>
| </template>
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing your Javascript with a bare minimum just to test your webpack configuration? Strip everything you need including the unit tests for now and double check your webpack configuration file.

Comment: I believe so.  There is a single test.spec.js file that loads a single vue component.  There is a tests/index.js that loads that file.  So a total of two js files, one vue component and then the karma.conf, and the karma.webpack.conf.

Comment: Did you use `laravel-elixir-webpack-official` or `laravel-elixir-webpack`?

Comment: "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got this to work.  Couple of things that might help.

I was originally running gulp, and trying to run tests in my vagrant box, to try to match the server configuration. I think that makes it much harder to find examples and answers on the internet.

Ok, so the main problem I was having is that webpack wasn't processing my components included in my test files.  I copied the webpack config out of the laravel-elixir-vue-2/index.js node module directly into the Karma configuration file and it started working.

The key is that karma-webpack plugin needs both the resolve and module loader configuration settings (resolve with alias and extensions) for it to work.

Hope this helps someone.

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // to run in additional browsers:
    // 1. install corresponding karma launcher
    //    http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/browsers.html
    // 2. add it to the `browsers` array below.
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ['./index.js'],
    preprocessors: {
      './index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          vue: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue']
      },
      vue: {
        buble: {
          objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
        }
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: '../img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            query: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: '../fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: './coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: '.' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
      ]
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting back on your own issue. I was deep inside the pain-hole today with this stuff. I took your config and modified to suit. 

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. The accepted answer did not fully work for me. The following solved my issue:

1. Install relevant loaders for webpack:

   `npm install --save-dev vue-loader file-loader url-loader`
2. Create webpack config file (note the format). The accepted answer produced errors citing invalid format of the webpack.config.js file. At least with me it did.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'vue-loader' }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          { 
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: '../img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            query: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: '../fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration

var webpackConf = require('./webpack.config.js');
delete webpackConf.entry

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        port: 9876, // web server port

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        reporters: ['progress'], // dots, progress

        autoWatch: true, // enable / disable watching files & then run tests

        browsers: ['Chrome'], //'PhantomJS', 'Firefox',

        singleRun: true, // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits

        concurrency: Infinity, // how many browser should be started simultaneous

        webpack: webpackConf, // Pass your webpack.config.js file's content

        webpackMiddleware: {
            noInfo: true,
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },

        /**
         * base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
         * This should be your JS Folder where all source javascript
         * files are located.
         */
        basePath: './resources/assets/js/',

        /**
         * list of files / patterns to load in the browser
         * The pattern just says load all files within a
         * tests directory including subdirectories
         **/
        files: [
            {pattern: 'tests/*.js', watched: false},
            {pattern: 'tests/**/*.js', watched: false}
        ],

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
        ],

       /**
        * pre-process matching files before serving them to the browser
        * Add your App entry point as well as your Tests files which should be
        * stored under the tests directory in your basePath also this expects
        * you to save your tests with a .spec.js file extension. This assumes we
        * are writing in ES6 and would run our file through babel before webpack.
        */
        preprocessors: {
            'app.js': ['webpack', 'babel'],
            'tests/**/*.spec.js': ['babel', 'webpack']
        },
    })
}
```

Then run `karma start` and everything should work.